# How do I fetch more than one ID in an API endpoint that only supports one ID per request?

Tags: javascript, json, api, coingecko

I'm using Coingecko API for price data and time (Unix) to output this in a chart, but the endpoint I'm using only supports one ID per request.

```
document.onreadystatechange = async () => {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    const coin = "bitcoin";
    const currency = "brl";




const response = await fetch(

  `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coin}/market_chart?vs_currency=${currency}&days=10&interval=hourly
  `
);

const data = await response.json();



const prices = data.prices.map((e) => e[1]);
const date = data.prices.map(i => i[0]);
```

i need that the function do the same also for solana, cardano, ripple, dash and litecoin

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far? Can't this be solved with a simple [`for..of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) over an array of the ids?

Answer (score 0):

If your API only supports one ID per request, and you need multiple IDs, you're going to need to make multiple requests.

One way to do them in parallel and wait for all to complete before continuing would be

```
const data = await Promise.all([
    fetch(endpoint1).then(response => response.json()), 
    fetch(endpoint2).then(response => response.json()), 
    fetch(endpoint3).then(response => response.json())
]);
```

The above will result in `data` containing an array of the responses for each endpoint -- `data[0]` will be the json from endpoint1, `data[1]` from endpoint2, and so forth. You'll need to step through them to get your prices and dates for each of the IDs (obviously it wouldn't make sense for the Promise.all() to try merging all the responses into one, because you'd have no way of knowing which price went with which ID.)

Comment: i've tried but it returns the data without these statements

    ``const prices = data.prices.map((e) => e[1]);
    const date = data.prices.map(i => i[0]);``

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at HTMLDocument.document.onreadystatechange

Comment: Did you look at the contents of `data` at all? I'll clarify the answer

Comment: I know this probably isn't the most optimized way but i have solved using your advice and changing these statements with variables for each coin